# Finish and start with other Threadgroup

Tags: jmeter

I'm using Jmeter to test multiple microservice.
The basic idea is to test a circuit breaker in a microservice environment.
Right now, I'm using two threadgroups, a master and slave remote concept.
One thread group creates uses 100 iterations and 1000 thread and creates
load against a front-end service, which sends request to a backend service.
The other group probes the backend service with 100 iterations but 1 thread.
If I’m not wrong the second threadgroup finishes way more early than the first one.
Is it somehow possible to sync those two?

And maybe another question.
As I scale the threads with the remotes, also the second thread group scales, is it possible to force the second threadgroup to use only one slave?

Comment: dunno if it's what you are asking, but if you are using the GUI, under 'Test Plan' (usually the root element) you can check 'Run thread Groups consecutively'. This will make the second thread group wait for the first one to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute "probe" thread group until "main" thread group is executing put the "probe" request under the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getThreadCounts().activeThreads > 1,)}
```

If you want to execute the "probe" thread group only on one machine of the JMeter cluster - put the whole construction under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use the following [jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

```
${__jexl3("${__machineIP()}" == "IP address of the slave",)}
```

The whole Thread Group should look like:

[image]